# How to populate failed time stamp date instead of "null" in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, timestamp, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to populate failed time stamp date. Because when the date value is not proper then unix_timestamp populates "null". In this case i want to populate actual failed date value in Timestamp instead of "null".

DataFrame:

```
    id,date
    1,161129
    2,961209
    3,110620
    4,160928
    5,021002
    6,160421
    7,160121
    8,100903
    9,077707
```

here  id 9 has improper data which not in a dateformate. so if i use `unix_timestamp("date",yymmdd).cast("timestamp")` it returns `null` for row 9. but i want actuall date if fails. i.e **"077707"**

expected output

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|               date|           
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2016-11-29 00:00:00|
|  2|1996-12-09 00:00:00|
|  3|2011-06-20 00:00:00|
|  4|2016-09-28 00:00:00|
|  5|2002-10-02 00:00:00|
|  6|2016-04-21 00:00:00|
|  7|2016-01-21 00:00:00|
|  8|2010-09-03 00:00:00|
|  9|077707             |
+---+-------------------+
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can do it only sacrifying `timestamp` data type. I.e. your final column will be of a String data type...

Comment: Or by inserting a default value like `1970-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: MaxU, timestamp datatype is must. can you please find any alternate.

Comment: philantrovert, you mean to say default value for all failed rows?

Comment: `077707` is not a `Timestamp`. How would you expect it to be stored as one?

Comment: Idea: you can create a third column (let's say `failed_date` as a String) and populate it with the original `date` value, but only for those rows where you've got NULLs for `date`

Comment: user8371915, i know it is not a vaild date. But we have a requirement to populate it. Becouse we are not suppose to drop any rows from table. so instead of null they are expecting us to populate the same value.

Comment: do you need a timestamp as output ? or a string which looks like a timestamp would be enough ?

Comment: Actually i am looking for Timestamp people are saying its not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional (when/otherwise) to select the raw or parsed date value.  It would look something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, when, col

data = [
  ('1', '161129'),
  ('2', '961209'),
  ('3', '110620'),
  ('4', '160928'),
  ('5', '021002'),
  ('6', '160421'),
  ('7', '160121'),
  ('8', '100903'),
  ('9', '077707')
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(data), ['id', 'date'])


df = df.withColumn('parsed', unix_timestamp('date', 'yyMMdd').cast('timestamp'))
df = df.withColumn('combined', when(col('parsed').isNull(), col('date'))
                                 .otherwise(col('parsed')))
df.show(100, False)
```

Comment: Its working great, But is there any possibility to change the combined dataType to timestamp?

Comment: Not if you want to store the failed string.  A column can only have one type.  It can't be both a timestamp and a string.

Comment: I am asking the possibility to convert the whole column to timestamp instead of string type. Not looking for two datatypes:D in the above comment i am referring combined column

Comment: Better than `when null then otherwise`, you can use `coalesce`

Comment: Steven BENET, can you please add your code. I need exact syntax

Comment: RyanW, cant we do with UDF?

Comment: @AshSr `df = df.withColumn('combined', pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce('parsed','date'))`

Comment: This works well. I have a small query, cant we use UDFs on Timestamp?

Comment: UDF to do what ?

Comment: cant we do this? `def udf_A(x:Timestamp):
    if x== null: return F.col("date")
    else: return x
udf_B = udf(udf_A,TimestampType())` to get the same output? i think we may get timestamp datatype with return type Timestamp() in UDF